# Torsion vs Curvature of a curve

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, plane-curves, curves

I was wondering if there is a simple explanation of the torsion and curvature in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of a curve.

The curvature measure somehow the acceleration perpendicular to the tangent vector, but what does the torsion tell me and how does this concept only become necessary in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n \ge 3$?

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to answer your first question: "I was wondering if there is a simple explanation of the torsion and curvature in R3 of a curve".

Torsion of a curve measures the planarity of the curve. That is, the curve is planar (i.e. it lies on a plane) if and only if its torsion is identically equal to zero. You can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_of_a_curve#Properties).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas for a good gif about it

Comment: This is a good start, but, perhaps the OP in interested in the meaning of the higher $n-1$-curvatures in $n$-dimensions? For $n=3$ we have curvature and torsion and the vanishing torsion insures planar motion. Is this still true in $\mathbb{R}^4$. What is the meaning of vanishing $2$nd and $3$rd curvatures? (see the wiki for the definition)

Comment: What I am trying to answer is the OP first question: "I was wondering if there is a simple explanation of the torsion and curvature in R3 of a curve." Maybe I will edit my answer to address this.